# Angular application built in Dockerfile crashes with error NG0203 despite working locally

Tags: angular, spring-boot, docker

## Problem Description

---

I am creating a docker image which runs a Spring Boot Application which hosts an Angular application that I am copying to the `static/` folder.

Running this locally works without any issues, but if I run the `.jar` file from the deployable docker image, the Angular application crashes hinting at [NG0203](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrOc1.png).

```
code: -203
message: "NG0203"
originalStack: 
Error: NG0203    
    at new It (http://localhost:8081/main.17bcaa919b5eb261.js:1:330791)
    at new Xn (http://localhost:8081/main.17bcaa919b5eb261.js:1:349170)
    at Ui (http://localhost:8081/main.17bcaa919b5eb261.js:1:349987)
    at vr (http://localhost:8081/main.17bcaa919b5eb261.js:1:350139)
    at e.ɵfac [as useFactory] (http://localhost:8081/main.17bcaa919b5eb261.js:1:388552)
    at Object.l [as factory] (http://localhost:8081/main.17bcaa919b5eb261.js:1:478649)
    at yd.hydrate (http://localhost:8081/main.17bcaa919b5eb261.js:1:477685)
    at yd.get (http://localhost:8081/main.17bcaa919b5eb261.js:1:476263)
    at Pt (http://localhost:8081/main.17bcaa919b5eb261.js:1:445529)
    at ut (http://localhost:8081/main.17bcaa919b5eb261.js:1:445630)
    at useValue (http://localhost:8081/main.17bcaa919b5eb261.js:1:474526)
    at yd.resolveInjectorInitializers (http://localhost:8081/main.17bcaa919b5eb261.js:1:477113)
    at new cu (http://localhost:8081/main.17bcaa919b5eb261.js:1:516602)
    at Kv.create (http://localhost:8081/main.17bcaa919b5eb261.js:1:516939)
    at http://localhost:8081/main.17bcaa919b5eb261.js:1:538752
```

Comparing the resulting `<filename>.<hash>.js` files they do have different names, but their content appears to *identical* except for some variable-names. Comparing the local build with the docker-image build using `git diff`, they appear to be overall identical.

My guess is that there's obviously something going on with the actual build of the Angular app. I've investigated the final `.jar` file and everything appears to be in order. Evidently, the `main.17bcaa919b5eb261.js` gets loaded and executed on the browser therefore it's being hosted as intended and accessible (no HTTP 401 or 404 etc).

## Local Build for Testing

---

To check the sanity of my setup, configuration as well as my own, I am build the Angular application locally with `npm run build` and copy the content from `dist/web-client` to the Spring Boot `resources/static` folder.

Running the server on http://localhost:8081, I can access the application as it should be.

## Build for Deployment

---

However, I want to dockerize the entire application and go with a straight-forward build-chain. I am not really doing anything out of the ordinary.

#### Build clients using OpenAPI

```dockerfile
# #####################################################################
# Stage: Build clients
#   - TypeScript (Angular)
# #####################################################################
FROM node:18.14.2-alpine as build-clients
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN apk add openjdk17
# +++ BUILDING CLIENTS USING OpenAPI +++
RUN npm run build
```

#### Build Angular application

```dockerfile
# #####################################################################
# Stage: Build web client
# #####################################################################
FROM node:18.14.2-alpine as build-frontend
ENV NG_CLI_ANALYTICS=ci
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install & copy dependencies
COPY web-client/*.json .
COPY --from=build-clients /usr/src/app .generated/cardit-api
RUN npm install

# Copy source code
COPY web-client/src src

# Build
RUN npm run build
```

I have built a docker image up to this stage and checked the `npm` (9.5.0) and `ng` (15.0.5) versions which look good to me.

#### Build final Spring Boot Application JAR

The next stage is also not that complicated. Here I am just building the final `server-*.jar` file for the actual deployment. As you can see, I am copying the Angular web-application from the previous `build-frontend` stage into the `static/` directory before calling `mvn clean install`:

```dockerfile
# #####################################################################
# Stage: Compile final jar
# #####################################################################
FROM maven:3-openjdk-17 as build-backend
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy server code & maven pom
COPY java-backend/pom.xml .
COPY java-backend/src src

# Copy static website (web-client)
COPY --from=build-frontend /usr/src/app/dist/web-client src/main/resources/static

# Build
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.m2 mvn clean install
```

#### Final entrypoint

This final stage is probably not necessary but still,

```dockerfile
# #####################################################################
# Stage: Entrypoint
# #####################################################################
FROM openjdk:17-alpine as server
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# {{ ENV variables }}

# Copying the final jar
COPY --from=build-backend /usr/src/app/target/*.jar .
ENTRYPOINT java -jar *.jar
```

## Comparison

---

On the left the output from the local build, on the right the dockerized output.

[image]